# How to update database without creating new primary key

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, singleton, state

I am practicing asp.net in Visual Studio and developing a bank application. My class diagram is in the picture below.

[image]

My `Account` sub class used both singleton and state pattern. Change state check in account state subtype checks what state it belongs to. All this is initiated by changestate method in BankAccount. While I do changes in my program for bank account balance it creates new Account State's `AccountStateID` and saves changes. I needs to edit record with change in state and balance and not `AccountStateID`.

My code for Account State subtype **changeStateCheck** is :

```
public override void ChangeStateCheck(BankAccount bankAccount) 
{
    if (bankAccount.Description == "Mortgage")
    {
        bankAccount.AccountState = BronzeState.GetInstance();
    }
    else if (bankAccount.Balance > 0 && bankAccount.Balance < 5000)
    {
        bankAccount.AccountState = BronzeState.GetInstance();
    }
    else if (bankAccount.Balance > 5000.01 && bankAccount.Balance < 10000)
    {
        bankAccount.AccountState = SilverState.GetInstance();
    }
    else if (bankAccount.Balance > 10000.01 && bankAccount.Balance < 20000)
    {
        bankAccount.AccountState = GoldState.GetInstance();
    }
    else if (bankAccount.Balance > 20000.01)
    {
        bankAccount.AccountState = PlatinumState.GetInstance();
    }
}
```

For bankAccount **changeState** is

```
 public void changeState()
 {
     if (this.AccountStateId == 1)
         BronzeState.GetInstance().StateChangeCheck(this);
     else if (this.AccountStateId == 2)
         SilverState.GetInstance().StateChangeCheck(this);
     else if (this.AccountStateId == 3)
         GoldState.GetInstance().StateChangeCheck(this);
     else if (this.AccountStateId == 4)
         PlatinumState.GetInstance().StateChangeCheck(this);
}
```

and just to update my edited record in database is add method `ChangeState()` in controller. ie.

```
public ActionResult Edit(SavingAccount savingaccount)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(savingaccount).State = EntityState.Modified;
            savingaccount.ChangeState();
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.AccountStateId = new SelectList(db.AccountState, "AccountStateID", "Description");
        ViewBag.ClientId = new SelectList(db.Client, "ClientId", "FullName", savingaccount.ClientId);
        return View(savingaccount);
    }
```

Comment: I guess you need to get record from DB by AccountStateID, update with new values and save changes.

Comment: i already did that and it populated all data from database and after saving the edit it makes new acccountstate id and saves it

Comment: Did you try to check requests using profiler? Are you sure that there are no aditional logic exists, that creates AccountState?

Comment: i am new to asp.net can u tell me what is profiler

Comment: this is utility that can track all requests to DB. [SQL Server Profiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx)

Comment: Hie i used sql profiler and its displayed exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent1].[Discriminator] AS [Discriminator], 
[Extent1].[AccountStateID] AS [AccountStateID], 
[Extent1].[LowerLimit] AS [LowerLimit], 
[Extent1].[UpperLimit] AS [UpperLimit], 
[Extent1].[Rate] AS [Rate]
FROM [dbo].[AccountStates] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[Discriminator] IN (N''BronzeState'',N''SilverState'',N''GoldState'',N''PlatinumState'',N''AccountStates'')) AND ([Extent1].[AccountStateID] = @EntityKeyValue1)',N'@EntityKeyValue1 int',@EntityKeyValue1=1014

Comment: And what query was executed for Update?